# Why do my android Webview component losses my php session?

Tags: php, android, api, session, webview

I have a question about Webview and PHP:

I am using an Android App that has a Webview Component.
The webview component shows a website.

I am using the same PHP code both for my website and for my Android webview component.

when I call an API page from my website, everything is OK, BUT
The problem is that when I call an API page from webview, the callback page does not know the original PHP SESSION id.

Any ideas why the webview destroys the session id?

Comment: You have some confusion here.  First off-  the webview or browser doesn't know what a website is written in.  You could be sitting there personally sending it in Morse code for all it cares.  It doesn't know what a PHP session id is.  All it knows is what HTTP knows.  And the way HTTP stores data between calls is cookies.  Your problem is that by default webview doesn't enable cookies.  You need to do that manually.

Comment: Thank you! can you please explain (or give me an example) - what do you mean by doing it manually?!